# How to use minimal character viewer in google docs?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, google-docs

Recently switched to the more minimal version of the character viewer so I could use it keyboard-only. It's such a dream not to have to take my hand off the keyboard anymore. Only problem: it doesn't work when I'm in google docs. I think google docs is probably the thing *causing* this problem, the same way it suppresses voice typing. But is there any way for me to override this so I can easily insert special characters while working in docs?

Comment: Have you tried with Safari or Firefox instead of Chrome?  What exactly is not working?

Comment: What operating system is in play here? iOS or iPadOS or macOS or some other? Version numbers and details like this can often be valuable to get you solid advice

Comment: I had this same question. Encountered in Mac OS and Chrome (multiple recent versions of each). Just tested with Firefox which is worse (suppresses both types of the character viewer).